# ArrayTypeMismatchException in copy constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I rarely get an ArrayTypeMismatchException in my program:

```
public Map(Map otherMap)
        {
            var cpyArr = new char[otherMap.PlayingField.GetLength(0), otherMap.PlayingField.GetLength(1)];
            Array.Copy(otherMap.PlayingField, cpyArr, otherMap.PlayingField.Length);
            PlayingField = cpyArr;

            var cpyTrans = new List<Transition>();

            foreach (var item in otherMap.Transitions)
            {
                cpyTrans.Add(new Transition(item.X1, item.Y1, item.D1, item.X2, item.Y2, item.D2));
            }

            Transitions = cpyTrans;
        }
```

The PlayingField property is a twodimensional char array.
Here is the output:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: (Types:
>   source=System.Char;  target=System.Char)

The strange thing is that this doesn't happen all the time, just occasionally.
The exception gets thrown at Array.Copy, but the error clearly states that the types actually *do* match.
How do I fix this?

EDIT: I should also add that the program is being compiled using the current Mono version and run on Linux. But I couldn't reproduce the error on my testing systems. The program is supposed to run on a server system which I sadly have neither access to, nor do I have any information about except that it also runs linux.

Comment: Can you create an executable repro?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `Map.PlayingField` property? I can only think of a possible way when PlayingField is `object[,]`

Comment: PlayingField is defined as such:  
`public char[,] PlayingField { get; set; }`

@usr What exactly do you mean by executable repro?

Comment: Code that anyone can run to demonstrate the problem. Right now nobody understands what's going on here.

Comment: Sadly a server executable is needed for the program to run. I also can't guarantee that the error occurs, as it does so only rarely on the server environment. On my own testing environment the error has never occured.

Comment: I would also like to ask if it is Windows server that the code runs on? Because no matter how had I try I was only able to get InvalidCastException. Maybe you can try catching this error and dumping the source array to some log file. If you do so, also add a full type name to next to each array element.

Comment: After some testing I managed to reproduce the error. When I'm running the application with Monodevelop, the exception is never thrown. Only when I build it with xbuild and then run it from a console, then the error happens. And no, the server is running linux.